# Maximum z-index value but header and footer coming on top

Tags: css

On [my page](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/), I have assigned the video area the maximum z-index value in Opera but still the footer and the header are coming on top of it. Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<div id="lightbox" style="z-index:16777271;">
    <p>Click to close</p>
    <div id="content"> <a href="#">
            </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the `z-index:10` from the `#main` rule.

Right now, this rule creates a new stacking context and all its contents are affected by its own z-index.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context for more info.